# Conditional search and replace using PHP and regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to hide all "p" tags in a HTML file that have an inline style with a  "left" offset of 400 or more.

I'm hoping some clever regex will replace "left:XXX" with "display:none" should "xxx" be 400 or more.

For example, this:

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:98px;left:472px;white-space:nowrap">
```

...would need to be replaced with this:

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:98px;display:none;white-space:nowrap">
```

It seems simple enough logic, but the regex and PHP is mind boggling for me.

Here is what I've been trying to do, but I can only get it to work line-by-line:

```
$width = preg_match("left:(.*?)px",$contents);
if ($width >399)
{
    $contents = preg_replace('/left:(.*?)px/', "display:none", $contents);
}
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated! :)

Wonko

Comment: What do you want exactly ?! Do you want to replace line2 instead line1 ?

Comment: Good question Fatemeh, thanks for asking. I need to replace "left:xxx" with "display:none" if "xxx" is greater than 400.

Comment: @WonkotheSane Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. You need to first write code that shows a *significant* attempt to solve the problem and show any research you did. You also need to explain in detail what the problem with the current code is so that it can be clearer to those answering. You can read all about it on the [how to ask guide page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you want code to simply be written for you, I suggest you instead hire a freelance programmer.

Comment: Now, you say *greater than 400*, and before it was *offset of 400 or more*. What is the exact requirement?

Comment: @WonkotheSane: You can use this regex: `$re = "/<p\\s+[^<]*style=\"[^\"]*left:\\K(?:[4-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])px/i";` (to be replaced with `display:none`). I am not posting, since most probably this question is going to be closed by "xeger"-people.

Comment: Thanks stribizhev. I'm a little slow at pasting my code and describing it. I didn't realise people were so eager to shoot down the new folk here. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't believe that regex will solve all the problem of the world:

Use DOMDocument to extract the p tags with a style attribute, extract the "left" value with a regex pattern from the style attribute and then proceed to the replacement when the "left" value is greater or equal to 400 (test this with a simple comparison).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$pTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

foreach($pTags as $pTag) {
    if ($pTag->hasAttribute('style')) {
        $style = $pTag->getAttribute('style');
        $style = preg_replace_callback(
            '~(?<=[\s;]|^)left\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*px\s*(?:;|$)~i',
            function ($m) {
                return ($m[1] > 399) ? 'display:none;' : $m[0];
            },
            $style
        );
        $pTag->setAttribute('style', $style);
    }
}

$result = $dom->saveHTML();
```

EDIT: in the worst scenario, the style attribute may contain `display:block;` or `display` with a value other than `none` after the `left` value. To avoid any problem, it is better to put `display:none` at the end.

```
$style = preg_replace_callback(
    '~(?<=[\s;]|^)left\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*px\s*(;.*|$)~i',
    function ($m) {
        return ($m[1] > 399) ? $m[2]. 'display:none;' : $m[0];
    },
    $style
);
```

Comment: Woah, it works perfectly. I would never have thought of DOMDocument. Thanks for putting me on the right track, you rock!

Comment: I can't understand what is `$m` ?

Comment: @Fatemeh: `$m` is the match array, index 0 is the whole match and other indexes are capture groups (1 for the first, 2 for the second, etc.)

Comment: aha, but $m[1] means one error was found in the matching ?

Comment: @Fatemeh: No, `$m[1]` is the content captured between these parenthesis in the pattern: `(\d+)` (so it is the value of the "left" parameter, the number).

Comment: I don't know why i can't get it ...! we have a array ($m), then what is $m[0] exactly ? and $m[1] ? If you think its concept is complex, ok, does not matter.

Comment: @Fatemeh: no, it isn't complex at all, the pattern `(?<=[\s;]|^)left\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*px\s*(?:;|$)` in the example, matches the string `left:472px;` so the whole match is `left:472px;` and is stored in `$m[0]`, `(\d+)` matches "472" (the parenthesis around `\d+` define a capture group), and the first capture group is stored in `$m[1]` so "472", that's all.

Comment: @Fatemeh: only with parenthesis and because this capture group is the first one from the left of the pattern. (so it has the index 1 in the `$m` array)

Comment: Ow i see, Just how do you set the content of `(\d+)` on the `$m[1]` ? how `$m[1]` and  `(\d+)` are related to each other ? tnx pal

Comment: aha, got it now :), then if i we have this pattern `...(test)...(test2)...`, then `$m[2]` is `test2` ?

Comment: Really i'm embarrassed for asking the question again, but i love to know: how this pattern has been creat? is this a new language ? The language of signs and symptoms... :)

Comment: @Fatemeh: Don't be. No, it isn't a new language, it is a string description system available in almost all programming languages (with some differences between them). You can find a tutorial for php to begin here: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-Regex.html and a more complete description here: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

Comment: Oh, So Regex is it ...!  I always had this question: What is Regex tag !! Then i got it now with your help. Tnx @CasimiretHippolyte, Really Tnx !

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it and it works correctly:

```
$string = '<p style="position:absolute;top:98px;left:472px;white-space:nowrap">';

 $test = str_replace('left:', 'display:none;[', $string );
 $test = str_replace('white-space', ']white-space', $test );
 $out = delete_all_between('[', ']', $test);
 print($out); // output

function delete_all_between($beginning, $end, $string) {
  $beginningPos = strpos($string, $beginning);
  $endPos = strpos($string, $end);
  if ($beginningPos === false || $endPos === false) {
    return $string;
  }

  $textToDelete = substr($string, $beginningPos, ($endPos + strlen($end)) - $beginningPos);

  return str_replace($textToDelete, '', $string);
}
```

output:

```
<p style="position:absolute;top:98px;display:none;white-space:nowrap">
```

enjoy it ... !